# Android: User Input into a Text Field WebPage

Tags: android, webview, android-edittext

[image]

I want the user to input these fields in a editText(s) and then login to the site using these fields which were previously entered (in a different activity). Also, how do I automatically click login without the user having to click it. By this, I mean in one activity, enter the login credentials and auto-login to the website in the background without the user needing to see a browser window or login using the website.

Preferably, I want the user to simply enter the URL to that page, the login info, and then eventually I want to extract information from the webpage without the user ever having to see a webview...

Furthermore, here is a link to a question posted by my colleague that expresses the same problem: [Android link navigation and box input on internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652639/android-link-navigation-and-box-input-on-internet)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to "automatically" login the user without having to click login you would have to implement a listener on text changed on the editText
something like this:

```
editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            //validate the user here
        }
```

but honestly I wouldnt recommend this since you would have be query-ing your server to check everytime the user enters/deletes a single letter. And if I'm right that is not efficient nor and uses a lot of resources (i.e. battery)

And for getting the parameters from the activity previously created use a `Bundle` on the previous activity and send the extras to the new activity (login activity) and then use the extras on your `onCreate`, like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
                  ....
              }
```

Comment: I don't think you quite understand. You may have misinterpreted my question. Here is a link to what I want to do, posted by one of my colleagues : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652639/android-link-navigation-and-box-input-on-internet