# Android link navigation and box input on internet

Tags: android, scripting, uiwebview, user-input

How can I get android to "navigate" through links on website? Say the first activity in my app allows the user to input their username and password, which would then be stored into Strings. Then the app would "enter" the strings into the username and password boxes and "click" the login button on the website. This "filling" and "clicking" would be done in the background, while the user sees a loading screen. This is the basic idea. So how would I get the app to "fill" in  the username and password boxes and "click" the login button?

Also, I do not own the website that I'm logging into. My app would simply ask for a username and password, and let the user log into the website, which is a gradebook type thing online for students to see. It's a convenience app. I also want this to be a native android app.

Ok, so this is an overview of what the application will look like:

***Activity 1*** -- User simply enters Username and Password (no web layout, nothing; just two editTexts)

-- Presses Login Button --

***Activity 2*** -- I need to navigate to a certain internet site and login without the user having to login through the website, I want to create a user interface (activity 1) where the login credentials are filled. In this activity, I want to somehow feed in these credentials.

So, essentially, I need to log in to this website on my own UI, and transfer that info to the website. Eventually, once logged in, I will need to use the .html code of the logged in page...

Note: As already stated, I do not have access to the website's database, etc. as I do not own and am not affiliated with the website.

Comment: Do you want to create a `native android app` or `web app` for this login functionality?

Comment: a native app, sorry for the unclarity

Comment: and login into the website? means you want to show website functionality after successful login?

Comment: actually after I log in, I wanted to somehow read the site's html code, then strip the code to look for the classes the student is taking. I have the html-stripping part down, it's just the logging in part.

Comment: sorry can't able to understand what you want to actually implement. Sorry i can't help you out.

Comment: what I wanted to do was this: take in user's username and password, log in to the school gradebook site, and read the site's html code. The problem was this: how do I log into the site without having the user to do it themselves